# Many-to-many with extra columns on join table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, join

Hi how will i setup this relationship? I alreade have a many-to-many realtionship but now with new features i need to add an extra column in the join table.

To make it simple i have a User class, Product class and UserProduct class and today it looks like this.

Product.hbm.xml

```
<bag name="Users" table="users_products" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" >
  <cache usage="read-write" />
  <key column="ProductId" />
  <many-to-many class="User" column="UserId" outer-join="true" />
</bag>
<bag name="UserProduct" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <key column="ProductId" />
    <one-to-many class="UserProduct" />
</bag>
```

User.hbm.xml

```
<bag name="Products" table="users_products" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" >
  <cache usage="read-write" />
  <key column="UserId" />
  <many-to-many class="Product" column="ProductId" />
</bag>
<bag name="UserProduct" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <key column="UserId" />
    <one-to-many class="UserProduct" />
</bag>
```

How should the cascade look like?
Now for the new features i created a new class UserProduct:

```
private int _id;
private User _user;
private Product _product;
private string _ownComment;
```

And created
UserProduct.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="" assembly="">
  <class name="UserProduct" table="users_products">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="UsersWhiskiesId" type="Int32" length="4" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="User" class="User" column="UserId" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Product" class="Product" column="ProductId" not-null="true" />

    <property name="OwnComment" column="OwnComment" type="String" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If i earlier have used user.Products.Add(product);
how will it look like now? 
How will i map the user and product? 
How do i update an excisting record? 
When i delete the user i want to delete the association to the product and not the product.

**NEW QUESTION:**
I have a page where registered users can collect products. On this page i now want the user to be enabled to hide some of there products. I have a gridview populated and a templatefield with checkbox. How do i update the UserProduct where i have a column "HideProduct". I have this code in a button.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.gvProducts.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = this.gvProducts.Rows[i];
            bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;

            if (isChecked)
            {
                int productId= 

Convert.ToInt32(this.gvProducts.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
    UserProduct up= new UserProduct();
    up.User = this._user;
                up.Product= DataManagement.CoreRepository.GetObjectById<Product>(productId);
                up.HideProduct = isChecked;
                DataManagement.CoreRepository.UpdateObject(up);
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your many-to-many relationship into two many-to-one relationships, just like in your database.

So, one User has many UserProduct items, and one Product has many UserProduct items.
A UserProduct has one User and one Product.